# Bubble sort not giving correct output c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I made this bubble sort code, but it doesn't seem to work can someone explain why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int numbers[5]={2,7,9,3,4};
    
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(numbers[j]>numbers[j+1]){
                int temp=numbers[j];
                numbers[j]=numbers[j+1];
                numbers[j+1]=temp;
            }

        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<numbers[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @john when i==4 , since j 's maximum value is i-1, j+1 would have the index of 4 . So its valid right?

Comment: Your inner loop is iterating the wrong elements in the wrong direction.  It should iterate from `(5-1)` to `i`. 
 With your current code, the `4` at the end of your array is only inspected once, so it can only be moved once.

Comment: inner-loop has to run at-least till `j<5-i`

Comment: @TruthSeeker `j < 4 - i`, for `i == 0` `j+1` should be maximum `4`: https://godbolt.org/z/TP9vWzbaP

Comment: @mch: yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work when you change the condition of the inner loop to `j < 4 - i`: https://godbolt.org/z/TP9vWzbaP

But that's not bubble sort, Wikipedia has a page about bubble sort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

The outer loop must run till it does not swap anymore.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int numbers[5] = {2, 7, 9, 3, 4};
    int n = std::size(numbers);
    bool swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++){
            if(numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]){
                swapped = true;
                int temp=numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
                numbers[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        n--;
    } while (swapped);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<numbers[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/E53dcejW5